# Writing the click event for the link in the <span> tag and <td>

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nested

```
<td role="gridcell" style="text-align: right; font-size: 13px" id="text_active_cell" class=""><span id="spanid"><span style="cursor:pointer;" data-row="[{&quot;Column&quot;: &quot;ID&quot;, &quot;Value&quot;: &quot;3844 &quot;}]" data-assigned-route="Wise" data-trackmode="aa" class="clsUps text-center clr-blue">15<span></span></span></span></td>
```

The count `15` is placed inside the `<span>` and the `<span>` tag is placed inside the `<td>`. It is linkable in the application. So, I have to write the selenium script to click on the link.

I have tried to write the following lines, but it is not valid.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("text_active_cell").findElements(By.className("clsUps text-center clr-blue")).click());
```

I am new to webdriver. Kindly help me out in this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. First you assign the variable count to the nested span inside `spanid`. Then use `click()` to click the element.

```
WebElement count = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='spanid']/span"));
count.click();
```

EDIT: Just realised your using javascript, but the xpath above will still select the required element.

Comment: It throws an exception error as read "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Comment: check [this](http://www.utilities-online.info/xpath/?save=0441625d-23ba-4609-baba-f20866442af1-xpath#.VVsKSZOOzEY) out, the xpath selects the text "15".

Comment: Test application have the Kindo grid(similar to excel) each cell contains links to redirect to another page. I have taken the relative path instead of absolute path using selenium IDE. For ex :- The absolute path is ".//*[@id='spanid']/span" instead I tried with the relative path "//tr[5]/td[8]/span/span". I got the output. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CSS Selector:

```
WebElement count = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#spanid > span"));
count.click();
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

use link find by text

```
wd.findElement(By.linkText("15")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use This**

```
WebElement count = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='spanid']/span"));
count.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

My test application using Kindo grid(similar to excel) each cell contains links to redirect to another page.

I have taken the relative path instead of absolute path using selenium IDE.

For ex :- The absolute path is ".//*[@id='spanid']/span" instead I tried with the relative path "//tr[5]/td[8]/span/span".

I got the output. Thanks to all